# onclick on input type image causes form submit

Tags: html, input, onclick, submit

**Scenario**

I have got this form:

```
<form action="EditShippingInfo.asp" method="POST" id="frmShippingInfo">
  <!-- stuff -->
  <input type="image" id="EditShippingInfo" onclick="javascript:checkShippingInfo(this.form);" src="/img/btn_save.gif" />
</form>
```

The `checkShippingInfo` function runs some input validation control. Eventually it runs a server side control via AJAX:

```
  function checkShippingInfo(form){
        /* runs validation controls */

        var data = setDataForAjax;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/include/checkAddresses.asp',
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function (m) {
                if (m == 0) {
                    /* I want to run form.submit only if m=0 */
                    form.submit();
                }
                else {
                    /* otherways I display a message */
                    alert(m);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

But the form submit is triggered **anyway**, even if m!=0.

**Question**

I want to trigger the `form.submit` only under a certain condition.
Does `input type="image"` trigger a submit in anycase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The fact**

The onclick event on a submit input shall always trigger the form submit.
**Unless** the onclick event handler explicitly return `FALSE`.

After this, two important details are missing in my code.

**The solution**

1. The `return` keyword in the onclick event handler.

   `onclick="javascript:return checkShippingInfo(this.form);"`
2. The `return` value in the `checkShippingInfo` function.

.

```
function checkShippingInfo(form)
{
      /* do the validation control... */

      /* do the ajax call... */

      /* I prevent the form submit */
      return false;
}
```

Comment: It's not a submit input though

Comment: @Dan. Strictly speaking you are right, even if what I found out this solution is valid for `image` and `submit` input type as well. Anyway, from [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input): 'image: A graphical submit button.'. And from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html): 'Creates a graphical submit button.'

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkShippingInfo(form){
        /* runs validation controls */

        var data = setDataForAjax;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/include/checkAddresses.asp',
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function (m) {
                if (parseInt(m) == 0) { //use parseInt here to get integer value
                    /* I want to run form.submit only if m=0 */
                    form.submit();
                }
                else {
                    /* otherways I display a message */
                    alert(m);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Checking return data types is a good point. But it is not the solution.